# Create facebook rest client using stored session_key (infinite session / offline_access)

Tags: java, facebook

In my facebook app, I figured out how to get a session_key by fetching the user's offline_access permission. (Using Facebook Java API)
However, what I could not find out:
How can I create an IFacebookRestClient using this key at a later point of time? Of course, as long as the session of my own app lasts, the client is stored within it - but I have no idea how I could aquire one in another session from that key.

Maybe I am just missing a part of the api... Any help on this is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well maybe it's just as simple as passing it to the constructor?

```
public FacebookJsonRestClient(String apiKey, String secret, String sessionKey)
```

Looks so....